# Binding custom objects as parameters in Micronaut http methods (@Get, @Post, ..)

Tags: micronaut

In my app I have a custom `Auth` object that I set as a request parameter in a filter.

No problems there, but now all my conrollers look like

```java
@Controller("/path")
public class MyController {

  @Get
  public Whatever get(HttpRequest<?> request) {
    Auth auth = request.getAttribute(SomeClass.AUTH_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    // code code code
  }

  @Post
  public Whatever post(HttpRequest<?> request, @Body SomePojo body) {
    Auth auth = request.getAttribute(SomeClass.AUTH_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
    // code code code
  }

}
```

I would really like to somehow "teach" micronaut how to treat `Auth` like `HttpRequest`, `HttpHeaders` and the other values at [Table 1. Bindable Micronaut Interfaces](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#requestResponse) in the docs.

Basically I'd like to turn the above in:

```java
@Controller("/path")
public class MyController {

  @Get
  public Whatever get(Auth auth) {
    // code code code
  }

  @Post
  public Whatever post(Auth auth, @Body SomePojo body) {
    // code code code
  }

}
```

Is there a way to do so?

I'm on micronaut 1.2.7. I tried

```java
@Singleton
class AuthTypeConverterRegistrar implements TypeConverterRegistrar {
    @Override
    public void register(ConversionService<?> conversionService) {
        conversionService.addConverter(HttpRequest.class, Auth.class, request -> {
            return request.getAttribute("").map(Auth.class::cast).orElse(Auth.anonymous());
        });
    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work as I hoped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a `TypedRequestArgumentBinder` bean.

You can look at `SessionArgumentBinder` as an example on how this is done because the session is just a request attribute as well.

Comment: Look like you are my best friend lately – thanks James!